# Why are methods of set not methods of dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

These are the methods that `set` has, but `dict` doesn't:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2020, 18:51:23) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(set(dir(set)) - set(dir(dict)))
{'__and__',
 '__iand__',
 '__ior__',
 '__isub__',
 '__ixor__',
 '__or__',
 '__rand__',
 '__ror__',
 '__rsub__',
 '__rxor__',
 '__sub__',
 '__xor__',
 'add',
 'difference',
 'difference_update',
 'discard',
 'intersection',
 'intersection_update',
 'isdisjoint',
 'issubset',
 'issuperset',
 'remove',
 'symmetric_difference',
 'symmetric_difference_update',
 'union'}
>>>
```

A few, like `set.remove`, arguably already exist for `dict`, but I am confused about why `dict` doesn't have all the public methods of `set`. Doesn't the key-value nature of `dict` make it jut a heavier version of `set`? Is there a reason methods of `set` are not in a sense "inherited" by `dict`?

Comment: Perhaps wrap your own dictionary type which includes these attributes, if you really need them.  (?)

Comment: "Doesn't the key-value nature of dict make it jut a heavier version of set?" No, these are fundamentally two different abstract data types, a set and map. Those other methods don't make sense for a map, although, python `dict` objects provide `.keys()` and `.items()` which return set-like *views*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed recently, see the discussion on implementing `set`’s full API [in this section of PEP 584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/#what-about-the-full-set-api).

Answer (score 1):

All the methods listed (intersection, symmetric_difference, ...) apply on the *elements* of the `set`.

In a `dict`, that wouldn't make much sense / add to the confusion to intersect or diff on the keys when the values could be possibly different.

So if you want to intersect 2 dictionnaries regardless of the values, what would the final value be?

```
d1 = {"foo":"1"}
d2 = {"foo":"2"}
```

what would `d1.intersection(d2)` return? `d1` or `d2` ? or should the values should be equal for the intersection to "work".

If you want to intersect 2 dictionnaries, first figure out what you *really* want, then code it either by intersecting the keys (converted as `set`s)

```
d3 = {k:d1[k] for k in set(d1).intersection(d2)}  # or d2[k]
```

or extract the tuples with `items()`, make `set`s of data (provided that dict values are hashable), perform intersection and convert back to dictionary.

```
d3 = dict(set(d1.items()).intersection(d2.items()))
```

if there are keys in both dictionaries associated with different values, the result is pretty unpredictable because keys are unique so only one would be kept (the last which is iterated upon, with sets which are unordered)

Comment: Out of curiousity, in the final example, what would be the result for the case you mention (same key, different values)?

Comment: it would create 2 entries since values are different. Values & keys would be treated equally, as `items()` returns tuples

Comment: 2 entries in what? not in a dictionary, since keys in a dictionary must be unique

Comment: If it creates 2 entries, then the format of the dictionary isn't the same as the original, right? Each key (and each value) is a key-value tuple from the original dictionaries?

Comment: oh right. Then you can't really know the result since sets aren't ordered. Editing answer

Comment: Note, use the set-like nature of views for more efficiency! `set(d1).intersection(d2)` should just be `d1.keys().intersection(d2)` or in this case, just `d1.keys() & d2.keys()`!!